# Download entire file [RDS logs]

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to download some rds logs which are about 1.8 gb in size.

I'm using the CLI as the download fails from the console.

I'm using the query like this:
`aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier instance123 --log-file-name general/mysql-general.log.2020-02-11.10 --starting-token 0 --output text > rdslogs000.txt`

Quoting from AWS doucmentation it says, "*To download the entire file, you need to include the --starting-token 0 parameter. The following example saves the output to a local file named full.txt.*"

However it doesn't work as exepected. I get the truncated file.

Answer (score 0):

You must read it in loop changing "starting-token" from where it stopped last time. Docs say that you can download 1MB at time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/download-db-log-file-portion.html